# Laravel 5.8 on demand notification error Call to a member function create() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I do this, the user receives email without error:

```
Notification::send($user, new TicketNotification($details));
```

But, when I do this, the user also receives an email, but with an error in the screenshot below

```
Notification::route('mail', 'email_of_non-db_user')->notify(new TicketNotification($details));
```

[Error: Call to a member function create() on null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOBgm.png)

Do have any idea why? How can I avoid this error?

I have to use On Demand Notification because I need to send a notification to someone who is not stored as a "user".

Comment: are you sure that $user->email is not empty, please?

Comment: @Dan i think u also send notification(saved notification to database) so change to only `mail`

Comment: @Thamer  yes I am sure $user->email is not empty. It is only an email adress like username@domain. The email address is from the same $user in laravel db.

Comment: @Dan I don't understand why you use Notification::route if this user exists in your db?

Comment: @Thamer Because, later I also need to send a notification to someone who is not stored as a "user".

Comment: @Jignesh how can I change to only mail ?

Comment: @Dan can you share with us your TicketNotification notification code, please?

Comment: @Dan pl see my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think try this one

in `TicketNotification` update `via` method with this for only send to mail.

But u r also saved notification into database..

```
/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jignesh, your answer works.

Sorry Thamer,  I should have posted the whole code from the beginning.

Before, it was :

```
return ['mail','database'];
```

Now only :

```
return ['mail'];
```

Then, there is no error anymore.

Here my TicketNotification that made the error:

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class TicketNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    private $details;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail','database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject($this->details['subject'])
                    ->greeting($this->details['title'])
                    ->line($this->details['body'])
                    ->line($this->details['links'])
                    ;
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'order_id' => $this->details['order_id']
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your via method to use the same Notification for all your issues:

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    $availableChannels = [
        'mail' => 'mail',
        'database' => 'database',
        'slack' => 'slack',
        'telegram' => TelegramChannel::class
    ];

    $channels = [];
    foreach ($availableChannels AS $channel => $driver) {
        if ($notifiable->routeNotificationFor($channel)) {
            $channels[] = $driver;
        }
    }
    return $channels;
}
```

You can now use On-Demand Notifications or fire the notificaton on users, without having to make multiple Notifications for each Channel or ON-DEMANDS etc...